# How do I destroy a block on a computer version of minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I am on the Minecraft app on my computer, no matter what I do, I cannot mine blocks.  Can you help me?

Comment: Does this affect all blocks? Are your hands moving when you try to mine the blocks?

Comment: Could you provide us with some more information? Can you do other things; have you looked at you keybinds? What version of MC are you running?

Comment: In addition to Nolonar's and rivermont's questions, what buttons are you trying to use/are pointing at?

Comment: Are you using a touchscreen?

Answer (score 5):

Some things to look for:

1. Are you using the right tool? https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breaking#Best_tools shows you what tools you can use. things requiring a shovel or axe are also relatively easy to break through punching.
2. Are you in the right game mode? If you're in adventure mode, you cannot normally break blocks. Switch to survival mode using `/gamemode s`. This requires your world to have cheats enabled.
3. Are you pressing the button correctly? You have to hold down the harvest button until the block breaks, not mash it.
4. (If multiplayer) Does the server have block protection enabled? Some servers have protections against breaking or placing blocks in or near the spawn chunk.
5. Can your computer handle it? If you have a heavily modded minecraft, or one with a big texture pack, you might experience severe lag that makes it look like you're not breaking the block.

Comment: I would also add the following: blocks recover if you try to mine a different block before the previous one broke. If a block needs to be hit 5 times, but you only hit it 4 times before moving on to the next, you'll have to hit that block for another 5 times until it breaks.

Comment: @Nolonar I slightly edited my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 3):

Did your hands move even you cannot mine? Try to make sure you **hold down** your button 1 (left mouse) until it breaks.

[image]

Or, is your hands not moving when holding button 1? Make sure you check your control settings and find the "Attack/Destroy". Beside it must be "Button 1". If not, change it.

[image]

Link for the default controls: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Controls
PC, PE, Console Edition default controls can be seen here.